# To verify that any item has been selected using Jquery Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation like this,
Iam trying to select a label using Id selector and sets its value..Due to some reason it doesnt seem to be working

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#Label3").val("hii");
            });
```

How do I verify that  `$("#Label3")`  has indeed selected the label.

The label is rendered like this:

```
<span id="Label3"></span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the number of elements in the result returned by `$("#Label3")` by looking at the `length`:

```
var label3 = $("#Label3");
if (label3.length == 0) {
    // not found
}
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is that you need to set `text` not `val`:

```
$("#Label3").text("hii");
```

Answer (score 4):

Only fields have a value and are therefore accessible with `val()`. To set the text of a `Span` you should use `html()` or `text()`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Label3").html("hii");
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Label3").text("hii");
});
```

Comment: Links to documentation:  http://api.jquery.com/html/ and http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: @ Jamiec + 1 Thanks Somuch   $("#Label3").text("hii") works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

`<span>`s don't have `value`s - you probably want  `$("#Label3").text("hii");`.

To answer the question, however, you can check `.length` - it will return `0` when no elements were found (which is a false value in JavaScript):

```
var label3 = $("#Label3");
if(label3.length){
    label3.text("hii");
}
else{
    alert("label wasn't found.");
}
```

See also:

- http://api.jquery.com/text
- http://api.jquery.com/length

Answer (score 2):

To verify if a selector has worked I'd normally do -

```
$("#Label3").length
```

I'd only use that during debugging though.

Answer (score 2):

Using the console in Safari, Chrome, or Firefox/Firebug:

```
console.log( $( '#Label3' ) );
```

Or

```
console.log( $( '#Label3' ).length );
```

Also, your element is a span, which does not have a value.  Use `.text()` or `.html()` instead of `.val()`

Comment: +1 .. Thanks for helping me out..I didn't quite get the console.log part..But Ill Google it and understand it :)

Answer (score 1):

To clarify what others have said, `val()` in jQuery is for getting the value of input fields.

Comment: That doesnt *clarify* what I said, it's exactly what I said :)

Comment: Thanks harpo for enlightening me

Comment: @Jamiec.  You are quite correct.  We posted at the same time, so my remark was directed at the first two answers posted.